# ADO.NET Entity Framework does not allow gridview clicking sort columns?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, entity-framework

I am using the ADO.NET Entity Framework data model. I send data from SQL to a GridView via ADO.NET Entity Framework.

But how can i sort gridview'columns click if i use EF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this for sorting an ASP.NET GridView object
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sorting.aspx)... :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you using an `EntityDataSource` ? Have you enabled the `AllowSorting` and `AllowPaging` properties on the GridView ?

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
        AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
        DataSourceID="EntityDataSource1">
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="......" 
        EntitySetName="......." 
        Select=".........." OrderBy="......">
    </asp:EntityDataSource>
```

Marc

Comment: i dont use EntityDataSource why i need it. I want to make it C# codes.

Comment: USE IT ! that's the way to get sorting and paging for free.

Comment: How to sort gridview columns by Clicking columns? i dont use below

Comment: void LoadProducts()
    {
        ABCBusinessFrameWork._SQLAccessLayer client = new ABCBusinessFrameWork.LoadData();
        Session["TaskTable"] = client.GetAllData("sp_GetAllProducts", CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        gvProducts.DataSource = Session["TaskTable"];
        gvProducts.DataBind();
    }

Comment: protected void gvProducts_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        //Retrieve the table from the session object.
        DataTable dt = Session["TaskTable"] as DataTable;

Comment: My advice: forget about doing this manually - USE the EntityDataSource! You'll save yourself a LOT of grief and code!!